# Создать sitemap.xml всего сайта с помощью django

Tags: sitemap, django

Я знаю как создаются sitemap с помощью Django.
Я собираю самые популярные с помощью:

```
sitemaps = {
    'news': NewsItemSitemap,
    'video': VideoItemSitemap,
    'gallery': GalleryItemSitemap,
}
(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps':sitemaps}),
```

Но при таком подходе теряются промежуточные страница, общая страница галереи, главная страница, страница "о нас". В общем эти страницы разбросаны, некоторые я даже не могу найти в моделях.

Как собрать подобные страницы?
Или как добавить урлы в ручную в карту сайта? Если кто-то может сказать, то на примере главной странице, и странице категорий ("/", "category/")

Answer (score 1):

Сделал через [Файл индекса Sitemap](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=ru&answer=71453).

Урлы которые не обновляются вынес в файл sitemap_static, а через встроенный инструмент от django сделал те модели, которые обновляются sitemap_dinamic. В итоге у меня 1 общий файл, и 2 с урлами. Гугл получает все страницы сайта.
Выглядит так:

```
sitemap.xml  
  |-sitemap_static.xml  
  |-sitemap_dinamic.xml
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, Вам поможет FlatPageSitemap.

Смотрите соответствующий раздел на http://djbook.ru/ch11s06.html.

Comment: Нет не поможет.
Главная страница, и страница категории не являются плоскими страницами.